# HID devices window popup appears even when no HID devices are available

Tags: javascript, webapi, webhid

I am using the WebHID api.  After a couple of test, I realized that the popup to select the an HID device appears even when no HID are available, which can be annoying the the end user.  I read the doc and I don't how to tell the api to just stay silent in case of no devices are connected.  Here is my code :

```
let device = null;
async function connectToHID() {
  if ("hid" in navigator) {
    let alreadyAssignedDevices = await navigator.hid.getDevices();
    const alreadyAssignedDevice = alreadyAssignedDevices.filter((device) => {
      return device.vendorId === 1151 && device.productId === 64161;
    });
    try {
      if (alreadyAssignedDevice.length !== 1) {
        [device] = await navigator.hid.requestDevice({
          filters: [
            {
              vendorId: 1151,
              productId: 64161,
            },
          ],
        });
      } else {
        device = alreadyAssignedDevice[0];
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    if (device) {
      await device.open();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome browser will always show a device prompt because user may plug a peripheral matching your filters after `navigator.hid.requestDevice()` has been called.